# Lotus Notes: Cleaning up log files from a data base is not affecting the database size and document count.

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus

Cleaning up of log files from a database is still not affecting the document count and database size. Please help.
I am using lotus Notes version 6.5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using "compact" (compacting database) after you clean logs..

http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/rnext/help6_admin.nsf/b3266a3c17f9bb7085256b870069c0a9/4bc933e0fb0898bd85256c1d0039d413?OpenDocument

"When documents and attachments are deleted from a database, Domino tries to reuse the unused space, rather than immediately reduce the file size. Sometimes Domino won't be able to reuse the space or, because of fragmentation, can't reuse the space effectively until you compact the database."

Comment: new user tip: if you find some answer helpful, you may want to upvote it :)

Answer (score 2):

If the doc count is not going down, perhaps you have soft deletions enabled.  See [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21091152) for details.